# Determine IP address and edit the config in single command

Tags: yaml

I'm trying to determine internal IP of a docker container and use that as an value in an yaml config file.
The command for determining the IP is;

```
docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' controller-control-plane
```

And, for editing the config in place, I'm using;

```
yq -i '.kubeslice.controller.endpoint = "https://<output_from_previous_command>:6443"'  values.yaml
```

Now, if I want to use the 1st command as an argument like this;

```
yq '.kubeslice.controller.endpoint = "https://$(docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' controller-control-plane):6443"'  values.yaml
```

Then the output is not coming as intended.

```
kubeslice:
  controller:
    loglevel: info
    rbacResourcePrefix: kubeslice-rbac
    projectnsPrefix: kubeslice
    endpoint: https://$(docker inspect -f {{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}} controller-control-plane):6443
```

How to do this correctly so that end point gets the correct IP value instead of the command string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you are trying to use a single-quoted string and a command substitution *within* a single-quoted string. A single-quoted string can't contain single quotes, and substitutions, in general, are ignored within single-quoted strings.

A follow-on issue is that you seem to want to inject the result of the command substitution *directly* into the YAML that you are modifying.  This is inappropriate as the data may need to be quoted and/or encoded.

Instead, assuming you are using Andrey Kislyuk's `yq` from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/, extract the data with your `docker inspect` command and initialize an internal variable that `yq` may use to set the value of the endpoint URL.

```bash
yq -y -i --arg addr "$(
    docker inspect \
        -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' \
        controller-control-plane
    )" \
    '.kubeslice.controller.endpoint = "https://" + $addr + ":6443"' values.yaml
```

If you're using Mike Farah's `yq`, you may instead round-trip via `jq` to properly insert the data:

```bash
yq -o json values.yaml |
jq --arg addr "$(
    docker inspect \
        -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' \
        controller-control-plane
    )" \
    '.kubeslice.controller.endpoint = "https://" + $addr + ":6443"' |
yq -P -o yaml >values.yaml.new &&
mv values.yaml.new values.yaml
```

This uses Mike's `yq` just for converting the YAML to and from JSON.  Any other program that can do this could be used for this, for example, [Stephen Levine's `yj`](https://github.com/sclevine/yj).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have to use double quotes in the `x = "y"` you passed to `yq`:

`yq -i ".kubeslice.controller.endpoint = \"https://$(docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' controller-control-plane):6443\""  values.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

We can use xargs to forward the output from the 1st command as an argument for 2nd command that edits the config.

```
docker inspect -f \
'{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' \
controller-control-plane | xargs -I{} yq \
'.kubeslice.controller.endpoint = "https://{}:6443"' values.yaml
```

output:

```
kubeslice:
  controller:
    loglevel: info
    rbacResourcePrefix: kubeslice-rbac
    projectnsPrefix: kubeslice
    endpoint: https://172.18.0.3:6443
```